# Jquery append text out of div section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to add text to a div sectionj using jquery but the text goes outside my desired div.. my html looks something like:

```
<!--CONTENT AREA-->
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_inner">
    <h2 id='titulo'>BUSCAR:</h2>
    KEYWORDS: 
    <input type='text' id='paramsQuery'>
    <input type='submit' id='botonBuscar' value='buscar'>
    <div id='results'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my js function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#botonBuscar").click(function() {
    var params = $("#paramsQuery").val();
    $("#column3_inner").append(params); 
  });
});
```

any suggestions to make the text stay on the desired width?

Comment: I reckon you missing some HTML here, please provide relevant HTML code, have a nice one!

Comment: Please show us the complete code. There's noe `column3_inner` div in your sample.

Comment: How could this question upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the results to an element not in the code provided. Perhaps you meant to put it in `#results` instead?

```
$(function() {
  $("#botonBuscar").on("click", function() {
    $("#results").append( $("#paramsQuery").val() ); 
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/icapuh/edit#javascript,html

If your text is overflowing your box, you can have a few options there. You could break the lines:

```
#results {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Or you could cause scrolling:

```
#results {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Or setup `text-overflow` to reveal ellipsis:

```
#results {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Saweet + 1 to read the questionnaires mind :)) **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qW8Fq/

Comment: sorry my mistake it is actually like u said ut i still have the same problem.... the text width is exceeding my div width

Comment: @user1391791 Set `word-wrap` or `overflow-x` on the `#results` element.